# How are participants in Composer related to members in Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have a question on participants in the composer. We have API to add participants to the network and I have seen in some samples we add those participants using the API using the connection profile of an Admin. When you are forming the network for real use case and especially in v1.0 and also I have seen in the HSBN service, you have to invite participants to the network and they can join and it automatically creates the peers for those participants. How do you map those participants to the participants in composer model. Are you still expected to create the participants in the ledger using the composer SDK. In v1.0 and even 0.6, when you add a participants, it provides an enrollment id. How do you map that with the participant information that you create in the ledger using the composer API to the enrolled participants in the ledger. Also when you add the participants in the ledger, is it really registering the participants ?

Answer (score 2):

Composer participants are modeled entities in the business network, whereas Hyperledger Fabric members are really represented by ECerts (enrollment certificates) used to access the Fabric.

So, each Fabric member can access the Fabric using their own certificate. Composer allows you to map an ECert to a Composer participant using an encrypted attribute in the ECert. This allows Composer to know what participant is performing an action, and to apply appropriate access control.

You should use the Composer APIs to create a participant, and then issue an identity for that participant. The act of issuing an identity will create an ECert with the appropriate encrypted attribute to map the ECert to the participant id. If you want to break that link you can revoke the identity for the participant using Composer APIs.

Doc links:

- https://fabric-composer.github.io/managing/participant-add.html
- https://fabric-composer.github.io/managing/identity-issue.html
- https://fabric-composer.github.io/managing/identity-revoke.html